# stop image from resizing itself

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image that seems to change its size depending on the parents height, well the parent/parents height. Point is I do not want the image to change size. Is there some way to stop it from thinking for itself?

```
        <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ivSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_save"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ivSave" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrap_content` means that the view will resize automatically. To set a fixed size use:
`android:layout_width="100dp"` and `android:layout_height="100dp"`

Use 'dp' instead of 'px', because these are device-independent.

Answer (score 1):

try

> **android:scaleType="centerInside"**

```
 <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
               android:src="@drawable/img_save"  
               android:scaleType="centerInside">  
   </ImageView>
```

[click here for more image scale type](http://etcodehome.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)